# click function is working after 2 clicks

Tags: jquery, function, click

I wrote a little script, that doesn't work.
I want to start a function after I click on the button. But my script needs two clicks. Sometimes it needs several clicks more. 
What do I have to modify that it's start working after the first click?

```js
$('#hotelfilter').click(function(){    
    $('#hotel').fadeOut('slow', 
    function(){
        $('#gastro').fadeIn();
    });
 $('#hotelnav').fadeOut('slow', 
    function(){
        $('#gastronav').fadeIn();
    });
 $.scrollTo('.gastro1', 1000);
return false;
});

$('#gastrofilter').click(function(){    
    $('#gastro').fadeOut('slow', 
    function(){
        $('#hotel').fadeIn();
    });
 $('#gastronav').fadeOut('slow', 
    function(){
        $('#hotelnav').fadeIn();
    });
 
  $.scrollTo('.hotel1', 1000);
 return false;
 
});

/*!
 * jQuery.ScrollTo
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Ariel Flesler - aflesler<a>gmail<d>com | http://flesler.blogspot.com
 * Licensed under MIT
 * http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
 * @projectDescription Easy element scrolling using jQuery.
 * @author Ariel Flesler
 * @version 1.4.12
 */

;
(function(plugin) {
  // AMD Support
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'], plugin);
  } else {
    plugin(jQuery);
  }
}(function($) {

  var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function(target, duration, settings) {
    return $(window).scrollTo(target, duration, settings);
  };

  $scrollTo.defaults = {
    axis: 'xy',
    duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1,
    limit: true
  };

  // Returns the element that needs to be animated to scroll the window.
  // Kept for backwards compatibility (specially for localScroll & serialScroll)
  $scrollTo.window = function(scope) {
    return $(window)._scrollable();
  };

  // Hack, hack, hack :)
  // Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
  $.fn._scrollable = function() {
    return this.map(function() {
      var elem = this,
        isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray(elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe', '#document', 'html', 'body']) != -1;

      if (!isWin)
        return elem;

      var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

      return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
        doc.body :
        doc.documentElement;
    });
  };

  $.fn.scrollTo = function(target, duration, settings) {
    if (typeof duration == 'object') {
      settings = duration;
      duration = 0;
    }
    if (typeof settings == 'function')
      settings = {
        onAfter: settings
      };

    if (target == 'max')
      target = 9e9;

    settings = $.extend({}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings);
    // Speed is still recognized for backwards compatibility
    duration = duration || settings.duration;
    // Make sure the settings are given right
    settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

    if (settings.queue)
    // Let's keep the overall duration
      duration /= 2;
    settings.offset = both(settings.offset);
    settings.over = both(settings.over);

    return this._scrollable().each(function() {
      // Null target yields nothing, just like jQuery does
      if (target == null) return;

      var elem = this,
        $elem = $(elem),
        targ = target,
        toff, attr = {},
        win = $elem.is('html,body');

      switch (typeof targ) {
        // A number will pass the regex
        case 'number':
        case 'string':
          if (/^([+-]=?)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)) {
            targ = both(targ);
            // We are done
            break;
          }
          // Relative/Absolute selector, no break!
          targ = win ? $(targ) : $(targ, this);
          if (!targ.length) return;
        case 'object':
          // DOMElement / jQuery
          if (targ.is || targ.style)
          // Get the real position of the target
            toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
      }

      var offset = $.isFunction(settings.offset) && settings.offset(elem, targ) || settings.offset;

      $.each(settings.axis.split(''), function(i, axis) {
        var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
          pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
          key = 'scroll' + Pos,
          old = elem[key],
          max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

        if (toff) { // jQuery / DOMElement
          attr[key] = toff[pos] + (win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos]);

          // If it's a dom element, reduce the margin
          if (settings.margin) {
            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin' + Pos)) || 0;
            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border' + Pos + 'Width')) || 0;
          }

          attr[key] += offset[pos] || 0;

          if (settings.over[pos])
          // Scroll to a fraction of its width/height
            attr[key] += targ[axis == 'x' ? 'width' : 'height']() * settings.over[pos];
        } else {
          var val = targ[pos];
          // Handle percentage values
          attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?
            parseFloat(val) / 100 * max : val;
        }

        // Number or 'number'
        if (settings.limit && /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]))
        // Check the limits
          attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min(attr[key], max);

        // Queueing axes
        if (!i && settings.queue) {
          // Don't waste time animating, if there's no need.
          if (old != attr[key])
          // Intermediate animation
            animate(settings.onAfterFirst);
          // Don't animate this axis again in the next iteration.
          delete attr[key];
        }
      });

      animate(settings.onAfter);

      function animate(callback) {
        $elem.animate(attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function() {
          callback.call(this, targ, settings);
        });
      };

    }).end();
  };

  // Max scrolling position, works on quirks mode
  // It only fails (not too badly) on IE, quirks mode.
  $scrollTo.max = function(elem, axis) {
    var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
      scroll = 'scroll' + Dim;

    if (!$(elem).is('html,body'))
      return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

    var size = 'client' + Dim,
      html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
      body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

    return Math.max(html[scroll], body[scroll]) - Math.min(html[size], body[size]);
  };

  function both(val) {
    return $.isFunction(val) || typeof val == 'object' ? val : {
      top: val,
      left: val
    };
  };

  // AMD requirement
  return $scrollTo;
}));
```

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
footer {
  height: 200px;
}
.hotel1,
.hotel3,
.hotel5,
.gastro1,
.gastro3,
.gastro5 {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
#choose {
  height: 500px;
  background: #AAAAFF
}
#gastro {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choose">
  <button class="btn" id="hotelfilter"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>Choose Gastro</button>
  <button class="btn" id="gastrofilter"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i>Choose Hotel</button>
</div>
<div id="hotel">
  <section class="hotel1" id="hotel1">
    <p>Hotel1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hotel2" id="hotel2">
    <p>Hotel2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hotel3" id="hotel3">
    <p>Hotel3</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hotel4" id="hotel4">
    <p>Hotel4</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hotel5" id="hotel5">
    <p>Hotel5</p>
  </section>
  <section class="hotel6" id="hotel6">
    <p>Hotel6</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="gastro">
  <section class="gastro1" id="gastro1">
    <p>Gastro1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="gastro2" id="gastro2">
    <p>Gastro2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="gastro3" id="gastro3">
    <p>Gastro3</p>
  </section>
  <section class="gastro4" id="gastro4">
    <p>Gastro4</p>
  </section>
  <section class="gastro5" id="gastro5">
    <p>Gastro5</p>
  </section>
  <section class="gastro6" id="gastro6">
    <p>Gastro6</p>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
  This is the Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: You have to provide relevant code in question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that hidden elements have no dimensions and browser can't calculate their offset either. Browser only determines this when elements are displayed

Try using the callback of the `fadeIn()` animation:

```
$('#hotelfilter').click(function () {
    $('#hotel').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#gastro').fadeIn(function () {
            // is visible now so we can scroll to it
            $.scrollTo('.gastro1', 1000);
        });
    });
    $('#hotelnav').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#gastronav').fadeIn();
    });

    return false;
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6mqvzxh/1/)</kbd>